# Replace connection Oracle

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures

I have to replace a connection in a function with a stored procedure that returns a cursor. I'm new to Oracle so I do not understand it very well.

The funcion:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SICAD.FC_SC_CONSUL_PRESUPUESTO_OPLAU (v_id_ciclo NUMBER, v_id_unidad NUMBER)
  RETURN SICAD.TP_PRESUPUESTO_TB IS

totales_presupuesto TP_PRESUPUESTO_TB := TP_PRESUPUESTO_TB();

codigo_unidad_oplau VARCHAR2(20);
ciclo_periodo sc_ciclo.periodo%TYPE;

 --variables nuevas modificación 1
v_tipo_unidad varchar2(3);
v_dsc_unidad varchar2(200);

BEGIN

SELECT trim(num_unidad_ejec_siaf), id_tipo_unidad,dsc_unidad_ejecutora INTO codigo_unidad_oplau,
v_tipo_unidad,v_dsc_unidad
FROM seguridad_unidad_ejecutora 
WHERE id_unidad_ejecutora = v_id_unidad;

SELECT periodo INTO ciclo_periodo FROM sc_ciclo WHERE id_ciclo = v_id_ciclo;

totales_presupuesto.extend;
totales_presupuesto(1) := TP_PRESUPUESTO(0,0,0);

IF codigo_unidad_oplau IS NOT NULL THEN

    case
      when v_tipo_unidad = 'SD' and v_dsc_unidad like '%GUANACASTE%' then codigo_unidad_oplau := substr(codigo_unidad_oplau,1,6)||'%';
      when v_tipo_unidad = 'SD' and v_dsc_unidad not like '%GUANACASTE%' then codigo_unidad_oplau := substr(codigo_unidad_oplau,1,4)||'%';
      when v_tipo_unidad = 'RCN' then codigo_unidad_oplau := substr(codigo_unidad_oplau,1,6)||'%';
      else codigo_unidad_oplau := codigo_unidad_oplau;
    end case;

    -- Tiempo Completo
    SELECT nvl(SUM("plaza_actual"),0) INTO totales_presupuesto(1).tiempo_completo FROM "SICAD_RelacionPuestos"@OPLAU WHERE UNIDAD like codigo_unidad_oplau AND "Descripcion" <> 'HORAS PROFESOR CAT ANUAL' AND "Descripcion" <> 'HORAS PROFESOR 1 SEM' AND "Descripcion" <> 'HORAS PROFESOR 2 SEM' ;

   -- Horas Profesor
    IF ciclo_periodo = 1 THEN
        -- Horas Profesor, 1° semestre
        SELECT nvl(SUM("plaza_actual"),0) INTO totales_presupuesto(1).horas_profesor FROM "SICAD_RelacionPuestos"@OPLAU WHERE UNIDAD like codigo_unidad_oplau AND ( "Descripcion" = 'HORAS PROFESOR CAT ANUAL' OR "Descripcion" = 'HORAS PROFESOR 1 SEM' );
    ELSIF ciclo_periodo = 2 THEN
        -- Horas Profesor, 2° semestre
        SELECT nvl(SUM("plaza_actual"),0) INTO totales_presupuesto(1).horas_profesor FROM "SICAD_RelacionPuestos"@OPLAU WHERE UNIDAD like codigo_unidad_oplau AND ( "Descripcion" = 'HORAS PROFESOR CAT ANUAL' OR "Descripcion" = 'HORAS PROFESOR 2 SEM' );
    ELSE
        -- Horas Profesor, ni 1° ni 2° semestre
        SELECT nvl(SUM("plaza_actual"),0) INTO totales_presupuesto(1).horas_profesor FROM "SICAD_RelacionPuestos"@OPLAU WHERE UNIDAD like codigo_unidad_oplau AND "Descripcion" = 'HORAS PROFESOR CAT ANUAL';
    END IF;


END IF;


RETURN totales_presupuesto;

END FC_SC_CONSUL_PRESUPUESTO_OPLAU;
/
```

I have to replace `"SICAD_RelacionPuestos"@OPLAU` and use this function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE function SIPPRES.FC_SICAD_RELACION_PUESTOS(p_fecha IN VARCHAR,p_periodo IN NUMBER)  RETURN sys_refcursor
as
l_cursor  sys_refcursor;
begin
sippres.SP_SPP_SICAD_RELACION_PUESTOS (p_fecha , p_periodo  ,  l_cursor);
return l_cursor;
end;
```

The cursor:

```
        CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SIPPRES.SP_SPP_SICAD_RELACION_PUESTOS(p_fechaAprobacion IN Varchar, p_id_periodo IN number,p_results OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
    AS  
    BEGIN
      OPEN p_results FOR
      SELECT 
           CASE WHEN LENGTH(SPP_RELACION_PUESTOS.ID_UNIDAD_PROGRAMATICA) = 4 THEN SPP_RELACION_PUESTOS.ID_UNIDAD_PROGRAMATICA || '0000'  ELSE
           CASE WHEN LENGTH(SPP_RELACION_PUESTOS.ID_UNIDAD_PROGRAMATICA) = 6 THEN  SPP_RELACION_PUESTOS.ID_UNIDAD_PROGRAMATICA || '00'  ELSE  SPP_RELACION_PUESTOS.ID_UNIDAD_PROGRAMATICA END END AS UNIDAD ,
           DSC_UNIDAD_EJECUTORA NOMBRE,
           SPP_RELACION_PUESTOS.ID_CLASE_OCUPACIONAL SECUENCIA,
           DSC_CLASE_OCUPACIONAL DESCRIPCION,
           SUM(CAN_PLAZAS_PROPUESTA) as Plaza_actual
      FROM    (SELECT a.*
                             FROM sippres.spp_estado_modificaciones a,
                             (SELECT id_modificacion, id_periodo, MAX(id_estado) id_estado
                                 FROM sippres.spp_estado_modificaciones
                                 GROUP BY id_modificacion, id_periodo
                             ) b
                             WHERE a.id_modificacion = b.id_modificacion
                             AND a.id_periodo = b.id_periodo
                             AND a.id_estado = b.id_estado
                         ) e,  SIPPRES.SPP_RELACION_PUESTOS 
           INNER JOIN SIPPRES.SPP_CLASE_OCUPACIONAL
              ON (SPP_RELACION_PUESTOS.ID_CLASE_OCUPACIONAL =
                     SPP_CLASE_OCUPACIONAL.ID_CLASE_OCUPACIONAL) 
           INNER JOIN SIPPRES.SPP_ESTRUCTURA_PROGRAMATICA
              ON     (ID_PERIODO_ESTRUCTURA_PROGRAM =
                         SPP_ESTRUCTURA_PROGRAMATICA.ID_PERIODO)
                 AND (SPP_ESTRUCTURA_PROGRAMATICA.ID_UNIDAD_PROGRAMATICA =
                         SPP_RELACION_PUESTOS.ID_UNIDAD_PROGRAMATICA)
           INNER JOIN SEGURIDAD.SEGURIDAD_UNIDAD_EJECUTORA
              ON (ID_UNIDAD_REFERENCIA = ID_UNIDAD_EJECUTORA)
        where
              e.id_modificacion =SPP_RELACION_PUESTOS.id_modificacion and 
              SPP_RELACION_PUESTOS.id_periodo = p_id_periodo and
              e.id_valor_estado = 26
           AND e.fec_estado >= to_date(trim(p_fechaAprobacion), 'dd/mm/yyyy')             
              GROUP BY  SPP_RELACION_PUESTOS.ID_UNIDAD_PROGRAMATICA,
           DSC_UNIDAD_EJECUTORA,
           SPP_RELACION_PUESTOS.ID_CLASE_OCUPACIONAL,
           DSC_CLASE_OCUPACIONAL 
           ORDER BY SPP_RELACION_PUESTOS.ID_UNIDAD_PROGRAMATICA;
    END;
```

Comment: You can't use a `sys_refcursor` in a query.  And replacing a table with a function that returns a weakly typed ref cursor seems like a very curious architectural decision.  Are you guaranteed that the weakly typed ref cursor will always return a result set with exactly one column named `"plaza_actual"`?  Is it possible that the cursor definition would change over time or across calls?

Comment: No the cursor will not change and I add what the cursor contains